Is there literature on balancing experiencing life with theorizing about it?
It feels easier to experience the world first and then articulate it. I can't seem to find anything on the topic of balancing theory and practice or why from a philosophical and logical perspective experience is preferable to study. It feels like intellect and experience are two sides of a coin -- sort of a duality. Experience is composed of qualia and seems unexplainable, especially if it's some religious or psychedelic experience. Surely some philosophers have tackled this topic.
How do I know when to stop chasing formal theories and instead focus on directly experiencing the world? Is there a middle ground, should there even be one? or should I pursue both in tandem? Is there literature on balancing experiencing life with theorizing about it?

"Theere are sooo many theories of everything, and noone talks about them. They're life changing! Or am i still a newbie and i dont see the faults? How can i see them then? Is there a book?" Why so? TOE is discussed in specialized communities and there are many books.

"objectless (???) Category theory, or the "Godel Escher Bach", or the concept of holism, or all sorts of -isms - "... you cannot mix all sorts of references out of context hoping to have insight.

Suggestion for improvement: please, cut 90% of the text reducing it to three or four initial statements describing the context, and then close with a Question:-)

Your objective is a good long term desirement.  But developing a coherent integrated model of reality -- has not yet been accomplished by anyone. You are in the right place though -- it is a philosophic project, not a math or physics one.  Mauro's comment that your question needs to be dramatically narrowed applies though.  "Tell me where i can find a good summary of a complete and accurate worldview" is not currently achievable, as I noted, so instead there are loads of fields of study that one must try to integrate oneself.

Have you read introductory philosophy textbooks?  That is the place to start -- understand the problems and approaches that philosophers have been using.  Then you can start asking more focused questions on advanced details.

In general, the problems of coherence and justification re much harder to address than anyone ever expected.  Philosophy is the hard problems remaining, after the easy problems have spun off into their own specialty sciences and analytical fields.

Welcome to the community! Here at PhilSE, we strive for short, fact-based Q&As rather than philosophical discussions (as a general rule). Take some time to read https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help and don't take closures personally. (Many first-time posters do.) :D I also let new contributors know that thephilosophyforum.com IS a site tolerant of open-ended discussion.

"developing a coherent integrated model of reality -- has not yet been accomplished by anyone" isn't really true, unless you append it with words to the effect of mathematically accurate, complete, universally accepted by each discipline of the hard sciences, and accepted as correct by the general public.  Because my personal model of reality is complete enough and coherent enough to satisfy my own "experiential" needs.  And I don't think the OP is in the right place to find answers.

@MichaelHall -- The hard sciences are not coherent, as science is a bottom up process, and integration to date is never more than partial, so every science is incoherent to itself. We have no emergence theory, and global reduction has failed, so science to science is also incoherent.  Science cannot justify itself, that is thru epistemology.  And science does not encompass the world, and science/non-science integration is entirely a TBD, hence incoherent.  Yes, we tend to ignore incoherencies in our own worldviews, but philosophy is about exploring the unexamined walls of our thinking boxes.

i think we agree then... (?)

@MichaelHall I am not sure.  My post above summarizes to "nobody has developed a coherent worldview", but you disagreed.  "Coherent enough to work with for most subjects if one ignores the problem areas and pretends they don't exist" is a pragmatic standard and one I follow for most subjects, but then claims of actual coherence need to be admitted to be false.  All our worldviews will generate contradictory inferences, and are subject to the principle of explosion.

OK, well it's hard to sift through all the word salad here...  FWIW, I don't pretend anything doesn't exist, I acknowledge that some things are unknown - That's different.  Anyway, my disagreement came with clear qualifying statements.

You seem to be yearning for what phenomenologists like Merleau-Ponti were after.

Good question! During early life the drama of intense emotions dominates, both in personal memories, and in observations of children. Prudence, the ability to govern action by the use of reason, is emergent from within the drama of early life. Baruch Spinoza reduces drama to emotions: a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. Humans are wired to identify sources of pleasure or pain. Feelings arise to inform and refine our ideas of cause. Aesthetics means feelings relate to arbitrary ideas. Prudence is the ability to gain/keep vital-pleasure via causal ideas.

@Utof Buddhism?

There are traditions which reject abstract disembodied reasoning as the ground to make sense of our lives from, notably Daoism & Zen which heavily emphasise how we use our attention, rather than intellect. Discussed here: Philosophers or philosophical traditions that reject symbolic reasoning
You might be interested in Heidegger's discussion of 'dasein' or 'the thing in itself', which he drew influence on from The Book of Tea, which draws on a lived enactment of Zen ideas through the practice of tea ceremonies. Discussed here: Did any doctrine follow Zen Buddhism? Phenomenology more generally, is described as 'the philosoohy of experience', seeking a programme that draws attention towards embodiment over abstraction.
No less a physicist than Stephen Hawking explicitly rejected the plausibility of a Theory of Everything, in this lecture: Godel & The End of Physics. Probably what you mean anyway is a Unified Field Theory, or a quantum-gravity theory. I would say you should read about Symmetry Groups & their summarising of continuous symmetries under transformation, which Noether's Theorem showed are directly equivalent to conservation laws. That is the language of unifying physics, and it has succeded in bringing together everything but gravity, into Quantum Field Theory. You might also be interested in this answer about what unification means: Is the idea that "Everything is energy" even coherent?
Hofstadter's Strange Loops and Tangled Hierarchies seem to offer the best hope of dealing with what Roger Penrose identified as a conflict between Godel-Incompleteness and how minds work. I like complexity-theorist David Krakauer's work on relating non-linear systems to this term he has 'teleonomic matter', I see it as very complimentary in understanding the emergence of and in defining living systems. Discussed here: What is a system?
I recommend asking more focused questions in future, on here.

Thanks for your answer, finally have something new to think about. If i may ask, how would you focus/specify my orginal "question"? Currently, all my attempts(be it on my own or with GPT) to shorten the post makes me feel like it's losing important context.

Zen reframes symbolic reasoning to reveal its utility and inherent limitations. Funny! My search for insight, drawn from the Blue Rock Record, turned up an answer by you @CriglCragl. See here: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/48842/looking-for-an-interpretation-of-the-blue-cliff-record. The first koan is, Does the dog have Buddha-nature? This evokes a relation (map) of concepts for dog, Buddha-nature, and whether some item of recognition has or does not have attributes arising as other items of recognition. The second koan is, Is the enlightened man subject to causation? Mu!

Two modes are available — religiosity and philosophy. Or in your language — intensifying the experience or deepening the understanding.
The Bhagavad Gita calls these two modes jnana and bhakti. And the whole (meta) point of the Gita teaching is to not fall to any one side. Taking this as the paradigm, see if you can find a system or school or teacher who will keep these two modes in equal balance.
In the mean time, your question contains an interim answer:

At the same time it seems like things like meditation or living with synchronicity are more helpful in getting closer to "feeling" the world,...

If you know that, you have a starting point.
This site is perhaps not optimal for this approach

Buddhism SE would be a good place to try.
